# How to get the curly caligraphic font for sigma algebras?

Tags: fonts

The title pretty much says it all.

Note that I am aware of the caligraphic font (cal, mathcal) which is actually what wikipedia uses too but books on the measure theory usually contain a much fancier font with many loops and I'd like to use it too if possible.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
...
$\mathscr{A}$
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll just add for general convenience that in plain one can use "\input scrload" and macro \scr.